# Is it possible to let Windows 10 detect multi monitor using command line?

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display

In the diplay setting dialog of Windows 10, there is a "detect multi monitor" button, if you aready connect to multiple monitors but there is less shown in the dialog, you can press that button to make other monitors show up in the dialog.

Is there a command line or API that can issue that order?

I'm running a Windows 10 guest on an Ubuntu host using QEMU/KVM/virt-manager, and have passed through a 3060 GPU to the Windows 10 VM. But each time the host suspend and wake up, the monitor connected to 3060 is black. It turns out that it is becuase the Windows 10 VM somehow "loses" that monitor after a suspend cycle and only the internal virtual monitor connected to virtual iGPU is still there. Pressing that "detect multi monitor" button can fix this and let Windows 10 show thing on the 3060 monitor, this is why I want to automatically run a command to execute that after wake up.

Comment: Yes, you can use task scheduler to detect machine wakeup, which then triggers a batch or powershell script to kick the monitors into place. Not sure if there is a built-in windows command that does this, but you can use a third party app to do it. Try https://tools.taubenkorb.at/change-screen-resolution/

Answer (score 1):

**Create the script:**

- Download and install [ChangeScreenResolution](https://tools.taubenkorb.at/change-screen-resolution/)
- Create a .bat script and copy/paste the following to it:

  @echo on

  CALL C:\ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=1920 /h=1080 /force
- Change the width/height to your desired screen resolution
- Save the .bat file to your desired location
- Test if launching this .bat script wakes up both monitors after sleep, instead of using Windows multi display toggle. If it works, proceed with the steps detailed below. If it doesn't, I may need to modify my answer.

**Now the Task Schduler Steps:**

**Open Task Scheduler:**

Press Win + R to open the Run dialog.
Type taskschd.msc and press Enter.

**Create a New Task:**

In Task Scheduler, right-click on "Task Scheduler Library" in the left pane.
Select "Create Basic Task..." from the context menu.

**Task Information:**

Enter a name and description for your task. Click "Next."

**Trigger Selection:**

Choose the trigger that best fits your needs. In this case, you would likely want to choose "When a specific event is logged." Click "Next."

**Log:**

Set the log to "System." Click "Next."

**Source:**

Set the source to "Power-Troubleshooter." Click "Next."

**Event ID:**

Set the event ID to "1." This event ID usually corresponds to waking up from sleep (you might need to double check this). Click "Next."

**Action:**

Choose "Start a program." Click "Next."

**Program/Script:**

Browse and select the path to your batch script. For example: "C:\Path\To\Your\Script.bat". Click "Next."

Now you just need to review your settings, and if satisfied click "Finish" and test.

Comment: Can there be an official command/api or open source solution?

Comment: The interesting is that I suddenly remember I have sort of an answer for this...https://superuser.com/questions/1489592/windows-10-batch-script-to-change-display-settings-for-specific-application/1494099#1494099